# Importing database into WAMP Server

Tags: mysql, wamp

I have a project sent to me by a friend and i am having serious issues importing the database into my WAMP Server. I end up getting Mysql error

Error

SQL query:

```
--
-- Database: `drivers_endorsements`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `admin`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `admin` (
`admin_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(40) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3
```

> MySQL said: Documentation
>   #1046 - No database selected

Comment: It's not really a big deal! The message itself is self-explanatory. You need to select an existing database first & then try your import.

Comment: Or you could possibly add this in your DB script that you trying to import - `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS drivers_endorsements; USE drivers_endorsements;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you have to create database manually or select the existing one in phpmyadmin (as mentioned WAMP server is used ) and then import the **.sql** file in it, and the database name should be same as that of used in application else will not work with desired application to which the database is linked.

Answer (score 1):

> It's not really a big deal! The message itself is self-explanatory. You need to **select an existing database first & then try your import**.
>   ***Or*** you could possibly add the following at the very top of your DB script that you trying to import -

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS drivers_endorsements; 
USE drivers_endorsements;
```